# DexFile not contain generated classes after add Kotlin configuration on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, dex

I have some custom annotations with annotation processing to generate some new classes in my applications. Then I use DexFile to find all this files.

```
final String apkName = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).sourceDir;
final DexFile dexFile = new DexFile(apkName);
final PathClassLoader classLoader = new PathClassLoader(
                    apkName, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); 
final Enumeration<String> entries = dexFile.entries();
```

Classes are generated with VelocityEngine from templates and annotated classes. 
The problem is when I configured Kotlin in my project my generated classes not in DexFile anymore if I app run in android 4.4. On Android 6.0 everything works fine.
Same situation happened to me when I tried to add some additional dependency to project.
I use Android Studio 2.1.2 and cradle plugin 2.1.2.

Comment: Did I get this right: problem is not Kotlin specific, it actually happens for any dependency you try to add?

Comment: I don't know. It's not like I add any dependency and it stops work. It's happened twice when I tried to add smack with jingle and now with kotlin. But It seems its happened not just because of dependency but also depends from lib if it possible. Multidex is on. And this problem not exist for android 5.0 and higher.